# Подключение готовой БД через RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, база-данных, adapter

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть готовая БД, содержимое этой БД я хочу вывести в качестве списка через RecyclerViewAdapter. Я так понимаю, что в RecyclerViewAdapter я должен прописать конструктор который передаст в адаптер данные из БД, а MainActivity запросит этот конструктор у RecyclerViewAdapter и выведет его в своем макете. Каким образом мне реализовать это, привожу основные фрагменты кода.

(**MainActivity**)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(СЮДА НУЖНО ПЕРЕДАТЬ КОНСТРУКТОР ИЗ АДАПТЕРА);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

(**RecyclerViewAdapter**)

```
    class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

(**Здесь нужно прописать конструктор, который получит данные из бд, затем данные прописать в onBindViewHolder**)

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card_items, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.nameHeadsRu.setText(AR_NAME[position]);
    viewHolder.nameHeadsAr.setText(RU_NAME[position]);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HeadsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(HeadsActivity.Extra_Names, position);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return AR_NAME.length;
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView nameHeadsRu;
    TextView nameHeadsAr;

    ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        nameHeadsRu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameHAr);
        nameHeadsAr = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameHRu);

    }
}
```

}

(**Метод получения данных из БД**)

```
      TheNameOfDatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new TheNameOfDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Не удалось создать базу данных");
    }

    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    cursor = myDbHelper.query("M_TABLE", new String[] {"_id", "AR_NAME", "RU_NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);


        CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor, new String[]{"AR_NAME", "RU_NAME"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        listHeads.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

(**Решил проблему**) нашел на гитхабе простой пример использования базы данных и вывод списка данных через recyclerview. Создал класс с переменной, конструктор этого класса прописал в recyclerview адаптере, а данные класса прописал в классе получения данных с бд.

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Проблема в том, что я не могу БД пропустить через RecyclerViewAdapter, чтобы содержимое БД отображалось в макете MainActivity. Как следует из кода, после того, как адаптер получит список из БД, то он должен отобразить его в виде списка, а далее нажатием на каждый пункт будет происходить интент.

Comment: в том коде, что вы привели только фрагменты реализации. Вам надо ее создать, но ответ по реализации будет очень объемным

Comment: @ZigZag там по сути весь код, я сейчас отредактирую и добавлю метод получения данных из БД, и моя проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю где и как этот метод прописать, чтобы мостом между MainActivity и DB был RecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: По идее вы должны из адаптера обращаться к холдеру, передавая туда свой объект из списка.У вас этого я не вижу

Comment: @plesser именно, вы не видите, потому что я задаю вопрос к тому, что не знаю как связать все это.

Comment: @Int404 у вас есть функция onBindViewHolder - она получается экземляр вашего холдера. Сделайте внутри класса холдера метод bind который будет заполнять ваше элементы. Он должен на входе получать эти параметры. вызывайте этот метод из onBindViewHolder

Comment: вам нужно создать модель, экземпляр которой вы будете создавать при помощи заполнения объекта из БД. Эту модель и следует передавать в адаптер.

Comment: В MainActivity в  mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(); в скобки я должен передать конструктор, конструктор должен быть прописать в RecyclerViewAdapter, и этот конструктор должен получать данные из БД, передавать их адаптеру, а адаптер передает их в MainActivity. Так я понимаю теорию этой работы, но мой вопрос в том, как поместить в конструктор данные из БД? Я могу поместить в конструктор данные из обычного класса, но не могу из БД. А далее во viewHolder я пропишу то что будет в конструкторе.

Comment: Переформулировал вопрос

Comment: нет, не совсем так.. в MainActivity в mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(); в скобки вы действительно должны передать данные для конструктора, и конструктор должен их получать.. из БД. Теоретически можно попробовать передать их прямо из курсора, но лучше организовать класс модель, который будет читать данные из БД и передавать их в конструктор адаптера.

Comment: @ZigZag можете дать ссылку с примером?